# Binding not working on GroupBox.HeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, header, groupbox

I created a custom header for my GroupBox like the following image:

[image: Custom GroupBox]

I want also to set a Binding on the Backgroud of this header, so I wrote the following code:

```
 <GroupBox Width="130"
                      Height="80"
                      BorderBrush="Black"
                      Margin="5"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Background="{Binding HColor}">
                <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="3"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="70"
                                Margin="-2,0,-3,-1"
                                Height="20"
                                Background="{Binding HColor}">
                            <TextBlock Text="Hubs"
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
 </GroupBox>
```

After execution, I the GroupBox's Background is colord in the right way, but **not the header !**

[image: Custom GroupBox]

Is anyone able to explain to me why it's not working well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Found !**

I had to make an internal binding in the Xaml, between the backgroud of the GroupBox and it's header. Like the followiing code:

```
  <GroupBox Name="HubGroupBox"
                      Width="130"
                      Height="80"
                      BorderBrush="Black"
                      Margin="5"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Background="{Binding HubColor}">
                <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Canvas.ZIndex="2"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="3"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="70"
                                Margin="-2,0,-3,-1"
                                Height="20"
                                Background="{Binding ElementName=HubGroupBox, Path=Background}">
                            <TextBlock Text="Hubs"
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
  </GroupBox>
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use like that ;

```
    <GroupBox Width="130"
                  Height="80"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  Margin="5"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Background="{Binding HColor}">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Width="70"
                            Margin="-2,0,-3,-1"
                            Height="20"
                            Background="{Binding Path=HColor}">
                <TextBlock Text="Hubs"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>

        </GroupBox.Header>

        <!--<DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Width="70"
                            Margin="-2,0,-3,-1"
                            Height="20"
                            Background="{Binding Path=HColor}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Hubs"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>-->

    </GroupBox>
```

Comment: It's not working like that ! I tried before, and the header was a string describing the Border ! and not it's view. Thank's @Ugur

Comment: Actually , I have tried and it is working. I have an image but they dont allow me to put image because of low reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can use this binding without element name

```
<GroupBox Width="130"
                  Height="80"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  Margin="5"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Background="{Binding HColor}">
        <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Width="70"
                            Margin="-2,0,-3,-1"
                            Height="20" Background="{Binding Background, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupBox}}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Hubs"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on your VM data instead of control properties

```
<GroupBox Name="HubGroupBox"
                  Width="130"
                  Height="80"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  Margin="5"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  DataSource="{Binding VMObject}">
            <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Canvas.ZIndex="2"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Width="70"
                            Margin="-2,0,-3,-1"
                            Height="20"
                            Background="{Binding ElementName=HubGroupBox, Path=DataSource.HColor}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Hubs"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
```